# Fixed Header not displaying properly on mobile devices

Tags: html, wordpress, mobile, header

I was asked to help with this website: [www.backincontrolbook.com](http://www.backincontrolbook.com)

On a PC browser, it looks like what it is supposed to look like. However, on a mobile device (tested on iPad and iPhone), the header occupies two lines, unnecessarily covering the first title on the page. Any tips for tweaking the header without doing a complete redesign?

I didn't make the website but I am an administrator for the site on WordPress.

Let me know if you need any more info.
Thanks.

Comment: Simplest solution I can think of is having a snippet of JavaScript grab the height of the fixed header on page load, then setting the top margin of the main wrapper below to that value. As a result, all content below would be visible despite the variable height of the header. (Let me know if you need me to provide an example implementation.)

Comment: Hi, I am a newbie at Javascript and HTML, do you think you could provide an example? I appreciate this immensely.

Comment: Sure, I'll add it as an answer below. Give me a few minutes to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a little bit of JavaScript to grab the height of the header when the page loads, then use it to set the top margin of the wrapper of the content below it. A small example I've set up helps to illustrate this solution.

**HTML (simplified):**

```
<div id="header">
    <!-- Header links go in here -->
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Content goes in here -->
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Only fires when document is loaded, attaching callback to window
window.onload = function(){

    // Gets element with id "header", and stores its height in variable
    var headerH = document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight;

    // Uses height to set margin-top of the content wrapper, which has id "wrapper"
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.marginTop = headerH + "px";
};
```

Now, even if the header breaks to multiple lines on a narrower screen, the content below it will not be covered, because it will have enough of a top margin to push it below the bottom of the header.

Here's a [JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/tWXF5/5/) of the above code, with a bit of additional content/CSS. Try resizing the Result pane until the header links break to multiple lines (and hiding the top of the page), then pressing Run - the content should be fully visible again.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions about this.

Comment: Thanks so much! That JSFiddle demo makes a lot of sense and looks like it works great! Like I said, I am a newbie. Where on wordpress can I access the website code to add this all in?

Comment: Ah, haha, I can't claim my limited expertise extends to WordPress, unfortunately. From what I've read, you'll want to be able to include this code in a template file, since your header is on every single page. You could add the JavaScript code between `<script>` tags in your "header.php" file (if it exists; I don't know what the file structure looks like on your end), which I think should do the trick. Though instead of an id of "wrapper", use "main", because your current site HTML uses that. Here's some more resources on this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Comment: Great, that makes sense. I'll take a look at the wordpress site and the templates. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Okay, good luck. If this post does help you solve your problem, don't forget to accept it as the solution! (Clicking the checkmark on the left of the post.)